# Unable to find one or more indirectly-referenced assemblies

Tags: msbuild, code-analysis

The CodeAnalysis return `Unable to find one or more indirectly-referenced assemblies. These assemblies are not required for the analysis. However, without these assemblies, the analysis results could be incomplete.`

But I can't find which assembly is not found. I tried to set MSbuild log in verbose but there is no more informations (see the log below). 
Have you an idea to find this assemblies?

Sorry, it's in french :

```
    Tâche "CodeAnalysis"
6>  Analyse du code en cours...
6>  
6>  Outils de ligne de commande Microsoft (R) FxCop, version 12.0 (12.0.21005.1) X86
6>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, Tous droits réservés.
6>  
6>  dataflowrules.dll chargé...
6>  designrules.dll chargé...
6>  globalizationrules.dll chargé...
6>  interoperabilityrules.dll chargé...
6>  maintainabilityrules.dll chargé...
6>  mobilityrules.dll chargé...
6>  namingrules.dll chargé...
6>  performancerules.dll chargé...
6>  portabilityrules.dll chargé...
6>  reliabilityrules.dll chargé...
6>  securityrules.dll chargé...
6>  securitytransparencyrules.dll chargé...
6>  usagerules.dll chargé...
6>  Addins.dll chargé...
6>  Initialisation du moteur Introspection en cours...
6>  Analyse en cours...
6>  Initialisation du moteur Phoenix en cours...
6>  Analyse en cours...
6>  Analyse terminée.
6>  
6>  REMARQUE : impossible de trouver un ou plusieurs assemblys référencés. Utilisez le commutateur '/directory' ou '/reference' pour spécifier des chemins de recherche de références d'assembly complémentaires.
6>
6>  
6>  Écriture du rapport dans D:\..\Addins.dll.CodeAnalysisLog.xml...
6>  Terminé :00:00:13.3407584
6>  Impossible de trouver un ou plusieurs des assemblys référencés indirectement. Ces assemblys ne sont pas requis pour l'analyse. Toutefois, sans ces assemblys, les résultats d'analyse pourraient être incomplets.
6>  Analyse du code terminée -- 0 erreur(s), 0 avertissement(s)
```

Comment: What is this `addins.dll`? It is no part of the regular Code Analysis process.

Comment: Addins.dll It's my  library to build

Comment: Did the CAlog give you anything usefull?

Comment: The CodeanalysisLog.xml file has nothing usefull

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  Run FxCopCmd from the command in order to see what the problem is:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe /f:YourDLL.dll /console /verbose > problem.txt

Scan the output for "One or more referenced" and the assemblies that it had problems with are listed just below that.

Comment: For me it says missing are: The indirectly-referenced assembly: System.Runtime, System.Threading.Tasks, System.Globalization, System.Collections

Comment: What do we do once we get the problem.txt. How to use the content of that file to improve our code?